# I get this error while building my flutter app: Error running pod install flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pod-install

I get this error while building my Flutter app.

```
[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/tm/64d5mqbn3wb9kfg7rx4t0vrh0000gp/T/d20231208-2941-1ub811p --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/tm/64d5mqbn3wb9kfg7rx4t0vrh0000gp/T/d20231208-2941-1ub811p'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reset
error: 4614 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Comment: did you try deleting pods & podfile.lock & try again.  Also, make sure you have a stable connection

Answer (score 2):

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1024M
```

Helped me (suggested in Atlassian's forum [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/error-6584-bytes-of-body-are-still-expected/qaq-p/2044744))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a stable connection as Heshan Sandeepa recommended, because **this issue is essentially related to network connection**. Also be patient because as [Nitish Kumar Singh's](https://www.nstack.in/blog/grpc-ios-stuck/) described on [this](https://www.nstack.in/blog/grpc-ios-stuck/) post:

> It downloads more than 1 GB of data when you Firebase(Firestore) to
> the Flutter Project. This is the reason why it took so long to finish.

I faced the same issue for almost a week, tried many solutions, and the only one that worked for me was finding a faster and more stable internet connection.